# Fetch Email Headers (Raw) Using Office.js API

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have build an Outlook OWA Add-In which is for both web and desktop application. There is a module where I have used **"Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync()"** to fetch headers of the mail which works perfectly on web version of outlook but when the same Add-In is loaded on the desktop version the code breaks because of mailbox version(1.4 or <1.8) compatiblity. As **"getAllInternetHeadersAsync"** is availble from mailbox version 1.8.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.4/office.context.mailbox.item

Is there any way that I can use to fetch the mail headers using **Office.js javascript API**? Other than Graph API, Office365 API or any other REST API.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you facing this issue on Windows desktop or Mac?

Comment: It's a windows desktop.

Answer (score 0):

The internetHeaders API for the Desktop client was introduced in requirement set 1.8. This means that all clients that support a requirement set <= 1.7 cannot use this API. The only solution here is to upgrade to a newer client.

If you want to use REST/Graph APIs to retrieve the internet headers of a received message, you can do that by adding the `$select=internetMessageHeaders` query to your REST call for fetching the message. See example 2 on this documentation page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#examples